# C言語のプログラムをOS無しでブートすることは可能ですか？

Tags: c

C言語のプログラムをOS無しでブートすることは可能ですか？
英語版で似てる質問がありますが別人です。

Comment: こちらのご質問は、適切にプログラムを書けば、それをコンパイルしたものをOS無しで実行できるか、という意味でしょうか？　となるとたとえば Linux という OS は C 言語とアセンブリで書かれていて、OS 自体もプログラムなので条件を満たすように思いました。通常ブートという言葉はプログラムに対してではなくバイナリファイルに対して使うので、どういう意図のご質問なのかを確かめたくて伺っています。こちらの質問に至った背景など教えていただければもう少し的確なことが言えるかもしれません。

Comment: OSの機能が一切不要で、自分でなんでもやるなら可能でしょう。例えばmalloc()のようにメモリを確保することをOSのシステムコールに頼らず、自前のプログラムでやるなど。普通のglibcは使わず組込用のlibcもありますね。crt0のようなスタートアップのコードを環境に合わせて書いて、main()をcallすればCでコンパイルしたコードに制御を渡せます。

Comment: OS無しというと「フリースタンディング環境」のことを聞きたいのでしょうか？C言語自体は「フリースタンディング環境」をサポートしていますが、nekketsuuuさんの言うとおり、「ブート」という言葉が一体何を意味するのかが曖昧で、このままでは可能かどうかの判断は誰もできないと思います。より具体的に、例えば「PC/AT互換機において、Cのみ(アセンブリとの組合せやインラインアセンブリは禁止)で作成したプログラムをHDDのブートセクタに書き込む。BIOSがそのHDDのブートセクタを読み込むことで、そのプログラムを実行出来るのか？」のような形で質問を編集してください。

Comment: らっしーさんのおっしゃるくらい詳しく書くには、回答が書けるくらいの知識が必要かもしれません。何が回答に必要か判断しにくいと思うので、とりあえず質問者さんがお持ちの情報をなるべく質問文に書いてくださると嬉しいです :)

Answer (score 7):

[c](/questions/tagged/c) 言語規格書は [c](/questions/tagged/c) によって OS 自体を記述することを想定しています。 OS を記述するような状況のことを [c](/questions/tagged/c) 言語規格書は「フリースタンディング環境」と呼んでいます。その意味で OS が起動する＝ [c](/questions/tagged/c) で書いたプログラムが起動するってことですね。

いわゆる「組み込み系」つまり家電製品など、ワンチップマイコンの開発においてはマイコン用コンパイラがマイコンの専用機能に対応しており、リセット解除直後処理（のことを、組み込み業界ではブート処理と呼びます）や割り込み処理などをすべて [c](/questions/tagged/c) だけで書くことが可能になっています。もちろん、アセンブラが無いと書けない超特殊な処理ってのもいまだにありますが、まあブート処理だけなら [c](/questions/tagged/c) だけで書けます。オイラ自身が経験者として保証します。

いわゆる Windows パソコンの BIOS/UEFI のリセット解除直後処理であればおそらく 99% は [c](/questions/tagged/c) で記述することができると思います。新しい CPU がガンガン開発され新しい機能が増えまくっている関係で、初期化処理には [c](/questions/tagged/c) コンパイラがまだ対応していない機能を使う必要があったりするので、どうしても残り 1% にはアセンブラが必須と考えていいでしょう。

---

質問が `printf()` 関数などごく普通の「ホスト環境」で動かす予定のプログラムを OS なしで動かしたいということなら、現代的答えは「無理」というか「無意味」。まあ OS を含めて自作すれば話は別っすけど、一般人が試みるにはコスト高すぎでしょう。

まあ世の中には（ワンチップマイコン向けでない）パソコン向けの OS を自作したいって人もいますので、興味があれば検索してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

組み込み向けのCPUではそれが普通です。
PCでやろうとするなら、初期化部分を自分で書くなりすれば可能でしょう

まあ、そのコードをどうやってメモリ上に展開するのか、というのをまず考える必要がありますが

Answer (score -4):

組み込みソフトの場合、WDTクリアをわざと止めて、CPUリセットをおこさせることもよくあります。

Comment: 質問文とこの回答の間に何の関係があるのか分かりませんでした。

Comment: ブートというのは電源ONもしくはリセット等でCPUを頭から走らせる方法です。組み込みでは何らかの異常発生時に、強制的にブート（リブート）させることがありますが、このときにWDTクリアを止めて、ハードウェアをリセットさせることがあります。C言語のプログラムの中でブートさせる方法として説明しました。